# How to create an organization in Github using CLI option or java api

Tags: github, github-api

How to create an organization in Github using CLI option or java api. any pointer would help?

Comment: According to the linked answer, it is not possible to create organizations or users via the API.

Comment: thanks for the pointers @Thilo

Comment: Is it possible to rename existing organization?